# How to make latex table to be more readable at printout level and spanning full page

Tags: tables

I am trying to make a latex table via an online latex table generator which works but it is not very readable. how can I make it readable? there is an indent in the right bottom corner which is unintentional while stuffing the raw data into the table so the whole text in the last column should be left aligned and can bullets be added on each line.

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{graphics}
\begin{document}


\begin{table}[]
\centering
\resizebox{\columnwidth}{!}{%
\begin{tabular}{|l|l|l|l|l|l|}
\hline
\rowcolor[HTML]{EFEFEF} 
\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}Equipment/\\ System\end{tabular} &
  AB Techniques &
  ABCD Category &
  \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}ABCD Type/\\ Description\end{tabular} &
  ABCD Size &
  ABC Findings and ABCDABCD \\ \hline
\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}ABCD Placement\\ ABCDEF\end{tabular} &
  \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}AR,AN,SAB\\ RE,DM,GH\end{tabular} &
  ABCDABCDEF &
  \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}Log data /\\ Textual form\end{tabular} &
  ABC Lines &
  \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}AB ABCDEFG the best\\ ABC score of ABCD\\ ABCDEFG to ABCD ABCDE ABCDEFGH\\ A ABCD ABCDEFG\\ Publicaly not available\end{tabular} \\ \hline
\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}ABCD's ABCDEF \\ ABCDABCD ABCDEF\\ ABCDABCD ABCDABCD\end{tabular} &
  LA,ABC,AB,AB &
  \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}ABCDABCDAB,\\ ABCDABCDABCDABCD\end{tabular} &
  \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}ABCDABCD\\ ABCDABCD ABCD\end{tabular} &
  \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}ABCDABCD of 100-550 \\ ABCDABCD.ABCD ABCDABCD\\ AB AB ABCDABCD\end{tabular} &
  \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}ABCDABCD ABCDABCD ABCDABCD \\ ABCDABCD approach used\\ ABCDABCD ABCD\\ Publicaly available\end{tabular} \\ \hline
\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}ABCD ABCDABCD\\ ABCDABCDABCD\\ ABCDABCD\end{tabular} &
  \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}ABCDABCDABCDABCD,\\ ABCDRF\end{tabular} &
  ABCDABCDABCD &
  ABCDABCDABCDABCD &
  \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}ABCDABCDABCD\\ ABCDABCDABCD\\ samples\\ ABCDABCDABCDABCD \\ samples\end{tabular} &
  \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}ABCDABCD ABCDABCD ABC ABCD\\ ABCDABCDZF ABCDABCD\\ABCDABCDABCDABCDABCD\\ ABCDABCDABCD\\ Publicaly available\end{tabular} \\ \hline
ABCDABCDABCDABCD &
  AB,GHmABC &
  ABCDABCDABCD &
  \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}ABCDABCDABCD,\\ ABCDABCDABCD,\\ ABCDABCDABCDABCD\end{tabular} &
  \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}ABCDABCDABCDABCD \\ ABCDABCDABCD\end{tabular} &
  \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}ABCDABCDABCDABCDABCDABCD,\\ ABCDABCDABCDABCDABCD\\ ABCDABCDABCDABCD\\ ABCDABCDABCDABCDABCDABCDABCD \\ ABCDABCDABCD ABCDABCDABCD\\ ABCDABCD\\ Publicaly not available\end{tabular} \\ \hline
\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}ABCDABCDABCDABCD\\ ABCD cooling fan\end{tabular} &
  ABCD,ABCD,AB,ABC &
  ABCDABCDABCD &
  ABCD ABCDABCDABCD ABCD &
  \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}ABCD ABCDABCDABCD ABCD 3 \\ ABCDABCD\end{tabular} &
  \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}ABCD ABCDABCD ABCD ABCD.\\ ABCD ABCD ABCDABCD ABCDABCD.\\ ABCDABCD ABCDABCD\\ ABCDABCD available\end{tabular} \\ \hline
\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}ABCD ABCDABCD ABCDABCD \\ ABCDABCD ABCDABCD\end{tabular} &
  LA,RA,GA &
  ABCDABCD &
  ABCDABCD ABCD ABCD &
  \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}ABCDABCDABCDABCD \\ ABCDABCDABCDABCD. \\ ABCDABCDABCD\end{tabular} &
  \cellcolor[HTML]{FFFFFF}\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}ABCDABCDABCDABCDABCDABCD\\ the best.\\ ABCDABCDABCDABCDABCD\\ ABCDABCDABCDABCDABCDABCDABCDABCDABCDABCD \\ ABCD ABCDABCD.\\ ABCDABCD ABCD ABCD \\ ABCD ABCD\\ ABCDABCD ABCD ABCDABCDABCD\\ ABCDABCD for ABCDABCD ABCDABCD on ABCD\\ ABCDABCD ABCDABCD ABCD.\\ ABCD ABCDABCD of ABCDABCD ABCDABCD\\ ABCDABCD ABCD ABCD ABCD for \\ ABCD ABCDABCDABCD.\end{tabular} \\ \hline
\end{tabular}%
}
\caption{ABCDABCDABCDABCDABCDABCDABCD}
\label{tab:ABCDABCDABCD}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

here is what it looks like after I zoom out the page.
i have already spent almost half a day trying different ways but every time something goes wrong.
[image]

Comment: never inflict `\resizebox{\columnwidth}{!}{%`  on a table, if you do you have arbitrary uncontrolled font sizes and rule widths and no hope of reasonable output

Comment: also the empty argument `\begin{table}[]` means "do not allow this table anywhere" LaTeX warns you about that and ignores the argument.

Comment: I have seen such markup here before, the "table generator" is creating nonsense markup so making it hard to customise the table `\cellcolor[HTML]{FFFFFF}\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}` is doing nothing useful at all,

Comment: @DavidCarlisle i have used the ´https://www.tablesgenerator.com/` 
the ´cellcolor` is missing a package otherwise it was used for header row colour.

i also tried scalebox, reiszebox and tabularx but all of them making more mess for me

Comment: yes as I say various people have asked questions about code generated by that generator, but almost always the answer is simply to write the table in latex. I don't see how the generator is helping. scaling is always wrong so scalebox, reiszebox  are equally bad. I know what `\cellcolor` does (I wrote the command) but `\cellcolor[HTML]{FFFFFF}` is white  background so doing nothing useful, and none of the nested tabular are useful, apart from possibly the ones in the head.

Comment: It's hard to tell from the ABCD filler text if the table cells are supposed to be paragraphs so could have automatic li breaking, or if they are some kind of list that needs forced line breaks.

Comment: yeah, i have added ABCD because I cannot upload the original content, the last column has lengthy text and instead of making it readable the table seems to be shrunk automatically. the last column text can be considered paragraph text and yes autoline breaks would help if the cell heigh also increase accordingly and text font stays in readable form

Comment: You have forced ureadable shrinking with `\resizebox`, latex would never do that automatically. Your original content is not needed but unless you want an answer more suited to typesetting DNA sequences  I suggest you make an example with words and without forced line breaks (can be any words, one two three...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Unfortunately table generators doesn't gives code which is hard to edit into some better, readable and clear form.
  -Are text in your cells really as you shown in document example? It is not natural text, long sequences of letters cannot be nicely broken.
- You should use smaller font in table (for example `\small` or even `footnotesize`).
- Table, as is, is huge. You shoud enable that text in cells can be automatically broken in several lines.

As starting point, how can you edit your table, may serve the following example, where for table is used `tabularray` package, columns are of X` type wit defined ratios of their widths:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{geometry} % determine page layout, wider `\textwidth`
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{tabularray}

\begin{document}
    \begin{table}[ht]
\small %\footnotesize
\begin{tblr}{hlines, vlines,
             colspec = { *{3}{X[0.9,l]} X[1,l] X[0.8,l] X[1.4, l]},
             row{1}  = {font=\footnotesize\bfseries, m, bg=gray!30}
             }
{Equipment\\ System} 
    &   {AB\\ Techniques}
        &   {ABCD\\ Category} 
            &   {ABCD Type\\ Description} 
                &   {ABCD\\ Size} 
                    &   {ABC Findings\\ and ABCDABCD}       \\ 
ABCD Placement ABCDEF
    &   AR, AN, SAB, RE, DM, GH
        &   ABCD ABCD EF 
            &   Log data Textual form
                &   ABC Lines 
                    &   {AB ABCDEFG the best\\ ABC score of ABCD\\ 
                         ABCDEFG to ABCD ABCDE ABCDEFGH\\ A ABCD ABCDEFG\\ 
                         Publicaly not available}           \\

ABCD's ABCDEF ABCDABCD ABCDEF ABCDABCD ABCDABCD
    &   LA, ABC, AB, AB 
        &   ABCDA BCDAB, ABCDAB CDA BCD ABCD
            &   ABCDABCD ABCDABCD ABCD
                &   ABCDA BCD of 100-550 ABCDABCD ABCD AB CDABCD AB AB ABCD ABCD
                    &   ABCD ABCD ABCDABCD ABCD ABCD ABC DABCD approach used 
                        ABCDABCD ABCD Publicaly available   \\
      \end{tblr}
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

But you may consider to rotate table by help pf `rotating` package. In this you should use `sidewaystable` case instead of `table`:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{tabularray}

\begin{document}
    \begin{sidewaystable}[ht]
\small %\footnotesize
... the same as before ...
    \end{sidewaystable}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: thank you for the template, if you see there is enough spacing available on top and bottom of the table, i believe it could be stretched further.
i dont mind if a row or two move to second page. rotation is also an option but i believe there is space which can be utilized

Comment: @awaisumar, instead saying "thank you" you can (at least) upvote answer (according to this site policy) or even consider to accept it if it solve your problems (on the best way). I transcript only first few rows, other I left to you.

Comment: i did that. i am not a regular user here so really did not know about policies but yeah your solution gave me direction and i will use it